# Is it possible to hide the Play Store App of a fully managed device without designating a kiosk app?

Tags: android-management-api

I would like to install many apps on a fully managed device and have the user launch the apps using the Android launcher. However, I don't want the user to see the Google Play Store app. Is this possible?

In the device policy, tried setting the installType to "BLOCKED" for an application with package name "com.android.vending" and it did not remove or hide the play store app.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7292363?hl=en) it said that some system apps are critical to device function and can’t be blocked. The package name `com.android.vending` is one of them so we don’t recommend removing or hiding it.